# Mysql join promblem

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM outlets 
INNER JOIN users ON outlets.owner=users.id;
```

The result is an array in which the indexes from one table match those of another table. Is it possible to somehow make such a request that owner = array, and there is already a structure
Result:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [owner] => 1 [name] => Рома [email] => admin [username] => admin [password] => admin [role] => 1 [photo] => [permissions] => {"menu": {"menu.shop": 1, "menu.users": 1, "menu.stocks": 1, "menu.clients": 1, "menu.finances": 1, "menu.partners": 1, "menu.products": 1, "menu.purchase": 1, "menu.dashboard": 1}} [status] => 1 )
```

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result. Take the time to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To return a result as an associative array use

- For old mysql extension: [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- For mysqli extension: [fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
- For PDO  [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with mode PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. You want to have an **owner** value **containing data of the user** (but not having data on the same level).

**Option 1**: By SQL you can do 2 separate queries and join results manually by PHP. But then you may have performance penalties.

**Option 2**: As a recommendation, if you need such a payload, just reformat your array as desired manually like this:

```
$originalArray = ['id' => 1, 'owner' => 1, 'name' => 'test', 'username' => 'test'];

$reformatedArray = [];
foreach($originalArray as $values){
    $reformatedArray['id'] = $values['id'];
    $reformatedArray['owner']['name'] = $values['name'];
    $reformatedArray['owner']['name'] = $values['username'];
    // ...
}

print_r($reformatedArray);

// ['id' => 1, 'owner' => ['name' => 'test', 'username' => 'test']]
```

Hope it helps.